# Text under a UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

The iPhone's settings application is build around a `UITableview`. In some views there are additional texts between cells. For example in "Settings" -> "General" -> "Network" there is the text
"Using 3G loads data faster, but may descrease battery life" under a cell with an UISwitch. Any ideas how to implement this?

Images of what I mean can be found here:

http://www.tipb.com/2008/07/12/how-to-disable-3g-on-the-iphone-3g-for-more-talk-but-less-speed/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a grouped table view, the `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` method found in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and the `UITableViewController` class handles this for you:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Footer text for first section, goes below cells in that group.";
    }

    return nil;
}
```

To place that text between cells, you have to have multiple sections and tell your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to place cells that you want beneath that text in the next section.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 6.1 you can specify footer text for Table View Sections in the Story Board.

Select your TableViewControler in the Story Board, then select the TableViewSection that you want the footer on.  Then in the Attributes Inspector, in the Footer field, enter your text.

[image: Add footer text to Table View Sections]

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your own UIView of any type (images, texts etc) and add them to the table cell, by using the `[[mycell contenView] addSubView:WHATEVER_IS_MY_VIEW_TO_ADD];`